# C# sometimes currency format does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems that sometimes the currency format does not work:

```
string Amount = "11123.45";
Literal2.Text = string.Format("{0:c}", Amount);
```

reads 11123.45

it should be:

**$11,123.45**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That code would never work - because Amount is a string, not a number. The currency format only applies to *numbers*.

For example:

```
decimal amount = 11123.45m;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:c}", amount);
```

(Note that using *double* for currencies is almost always a bad idea, as double can't exactly represent many decimal numbers. Decimal is a more appropriate type for financial data.)

Answer (score 2):

It's because Amount is a string instead of a numeric.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my situation

```
string Amount = "11123.45";
amount2 = amount.AsDecimal();
string.Format("{0:c}", @amount2)
```